# wireless not showing up in network manager applet

Tags: wireless, network-manager

there is only the wired connection option available when the menu drops down. i have installed a belkin wireless g card for my desktop. it has been used before on this version of ubuntu 10.10, but after upgrading it shows only wired networks. enable networking and enable notifications have both been ticked. still only wired networks coming. im using ubuntu 10.10 maverick meerkat on my desktop comp and im an absolute begginer at ubuntu. can some one please help me re enable wireless on my comp?

Comment: As koanhead already suggested, please tell us if the output of ifconfig shows a wireless interface like 'wlan0'.

Comment: To avoid issues like this in the future, try a live session (preferably live USB) to see if everything works before upgrading.

Comment: This question appears to be abandonded, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, are you connected to the internet? If so, try clicking System>Administration>Aditional Drivers

This will bring up non open-drivers. This worked for my wife's computer. I'm not really sure which cards require this or not, but worth a short in my books.

Comment: im connected to the internet by an ethernet cable. i tried the additional drivers method u said but there were no options there. it said that there were no proprietary drivers installed. i have installed my wireless card using the windows wireless drivers application and the card has worked fine untill i up[graded ubuntu. do u have any other suggestions i can use?

Comment: upgraded to Natty (11.04)? I'd file a bug for this. Sounds like a regresssion. Though I'm not experienced enough to tell you if the problem is with network manager or the windows wireless drivers program. Someone should set the right package for you when it's triaged. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/

Comment: so how do i get wireless back?

Comment: you'd be suprised how quickly the bug people work. I had an issue on my printer/scanner and it was sorted in an afternoon. Point is, it used to work,and now doesn't that means there's an issue that needs to be looked at. Truly is the best part of Ubuntu. Can't ask Microsoft or Apple directly to fix problems with the code.

Answer (score 2):

try out wicd ... its a alternative to NetworkManager and works much better ... I had the same issues and WiCD sorted it out ...

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `ifconfig` in a terminal, and look for an entry labeled wlan0 or ra0 or wifi0 or similar. If it shows up in ifconfig your drivers are not the issue. If it isn't there, then go ahead and follow Kyle Clarke's advice above.